# javascript does not execute (codeigniter) php script after window.print()

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

i have this javascript that checks if payment is equal or greater than total,
a window.print executes likewise a redirect page occurs, but it only print
but does not redirect.

view page:

```
<script>
function printpage() 
{
      var 
          total = parseFloat($(':input[name="total"]').val(),10),
      cash = parseFloat($(':input[name="cash"]').val(),10),
      charge = parseFloat($(':input[name="charge"]').val(),10),   
      payment = (cash + charge);

      if(payment>= total){

      window.print();
      }else{

      return false;
      }
}
</script>

im not good at javascript. 
here is some more details:  
<form action="bills/settle" method="post">  
<input type="text" name="cash">  
<input type="text" name="charge">
<input type="text" name="total" value="<?php echo $total"> 
<input type="submit" onclick="printpage()"   
</form>
```

controller page:

```
function settle(){  
$payment = $this->input->post('cash')+ $this->input->post('charge');  
$total = $this->input->post('total');  
$data = ('cash'=>$this->input->post('cash'), so on.....)    

    if($payment >=$total)
    {  

        $this->load->model('process');  
        $this->process->close_bill($data);  

    } else {
       redirect('msg','refresh');  
    }  
}
```

*other notes,
if payment is OK: 
it prints, inserts data's to database but does not redirect.
the redirect script is in my model after a successful db insert.

if payment is not OK:(no problem on this side)
it redirects to msg page,

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the javascript; it was an honest mistake on your part:

```
<input type="text" name="total" value="<?php echo $total">
```

should instead be:

```
<input type="text" name="total" value="<?php echo $total; ?>">
```

Also, it would help if you had `display_errors` set to `on` and `error_reporting` set to `E_ALL` while you are doing development, so you can see when errors occur.

Comment: sorry, ive been off the internet for a week, thanks for the response.